# JavaScript not being loaded. Tried everything I can think of

Tags: php, javascript, css, xhtml, joomla

[Swimwire.com](http://swimwire.com) is no longer loading JavaScript properly since I installed an update to its Social module, JomSocial. It's something to do with JomSocial, I'm certain, since on the homepage no JavaScript properly works (there's a blue bar along the top that should be clickable and contain the words 'Open Control Panel', but it doesn't load). Whereas if I visit a page not displaying JomSocial content the JavaScript will happily load.

I got some help with this yesterday but unfortuantely I'm still very stuck. I'm a novice at JavaScript and Safari throws me the error

> TypeError: Result of expression '$'
>   [undefined] is not a function.
>   /modules/mod_rokslideshow/tmpl/slideshow.js:73TypeError:
>   Result of expression '$' [undefined]
>   is not a function.
>   2/media/system/js/mootools.js:54TypeError:
>   Type error

I'm not too sure at all how to interpret this. I'm certain that something in JomSocial is causing a conflict but don't know really how to go about addressing this.

Jack

Comment: No way for us to test when it is in maintenance mode.

Comment: Sorry, opened the site up again. Still searching for an answer though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple libraries which define `$`; I know that jQuery and Prototype do this, not sure about MooTools (which I see in your error message). So, based on that message, I can only guess that you have, in one way or another, loaded two libraries which both use `$`.

The jQuery solution for this is to use noConflict: http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict. Not knowing both sides of the clash, and not being able to access the site myself, that's the best I can do.

---

**Edit:** Did you try any of the solutions that MooTools suggests? http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode/

Comment: Mootools does have $ defined as well. The new versions let you use document.id instead in case someone else has defined $

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've opened the site up again - sorry, I totally forgot! :D

If you examine the source, however, you will see jQuery.noConflict()... :(

Answer (score 1):

Your `jQuery.noConflict()` most likely comes after some other scripts are loaded and attempt to use `$`.

Another thing... `jQuery.noConflict()` may not work if it's included before the other library, as it's in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that even if you have jQuery in no conflict mode, that you have MooTools loading **first**. If you load jQuery, put it into no conflict mode, then load MooTools, it will fail. I wrote some documentation on this in my book: http://www.packtpub.com/files/learning-joomla-1-5-extension-development-sample-chapter-8-using-javascript-effects.pdf

If you make sure that the following call is made before jQuery gets added to the document, it should load MooTools before jQuery:

```
JHTML::_('behavior.mootools');
```